# Save CRS in .tif instead of .aux.xml when reprojecting `.tif` using `gdalwarp`

Tags: gis, gdal

I am using `gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:8857 -r bilinear -wo NUM_THREADS=20 -multi in.tif out.tif` to change the CRS of `in.tif`. This returns the desired `out.tif` file but also `out.tif.aux.xml` which contains the CRS information. This means if I delete `out.tif.aux.xml` the CRS information is lost and `gdalinfo out.tif` does not show the CRS information anymore.

Is there a way to save specify that the CRS is saved in `out.tif`? This must be somehow possible because `in.tif` also contains its CRS information.

For some reason I get the `out.tif` with CRS on a different machine with the exact same command. I wonder what to look for.

EDIT: Everything works fine with EPSG:4326. What is the issue with EPSG:8857?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the XML file is just classification data not the projection

Answer (score 0):

The XML gets to store everything that GDAL cannot store in the output format because it does not support it.

GeoTIFF supports having a projection, but not every possible way to encode it. Is there anything special about the projection in the input file? Also try the latest GDAL, I just tried with 3.4.1 and it can write `EPSG:8857` directly in the GeoTIFF for sure. Also try setting the environment variable
`GDAL_PAM_ENABLED` to `NO`.